# Am I using the wrong variable type when calculating dates?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a statement like this:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var futureDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 18);

int spaceBetweenDays = (futureDate - currentDate).Days;

switch (spaceBetweenDays)
{   
    case 200:
        ...do stuff
        break;
    case 175:
        ...do stuff
        break;
    case 150:
        ...do stuff
        break;
    case 125:
        ...do stuff
        break;
    case 100:
        ...do stuff
        break;
    case 75:
        ...do different stuff
```

I want to run a block code when the `spaceBetweenDays` is a certain number.

When testing, I can never get the code to work. Even when the value of `spaceBetweenDays` is one of the test values(200, 175, 150, etc), it never runs.

So in Visual Studio, when I hover over the numbers after the `case` statement, It is saying it is a  `System.Int32`.

But `spaceBetweenDays` is an `int`.

Could this be why it's not working?

Comment: `int` is a keyword that refers to `System.Int32` - they are the same. Just like `string` refers to `System.String`. It's unlikely this is the issue.

Comment: _"Even when the value of spaceBetweenDays is one of the test values"_ - do you _think_ it _should have been_ one of the values or did you _verify_ it _is_ one of the values?

Comment: So this will not print 200 to the console? `int spaceBetweenDays = 200;
switch (spaceBetweenDays)
{ case 200 : Console.WriteLine(spaceBetweenDays); break; }`

Comment: @Magnus I was doing a `Console.WriteLine(spaceBetweenDays);` before the `switch` statement started.  My fault, I didn't even thing of doing it in the `switch` statement.

Comment: the spaceBetweenDays is 128 and the switch is working , fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/L4vQnw

Comment: @Fildor I tested the value before the switch statment like `Console.WriteLine(spaceBetweenDays);`  I never thought of putting it in the actual switch statement :(

Comment: Is there something you are not telling us? Do you mean to work with intervals or should nothing happen if `spaceBetweenDays` is 179 or another non-test value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right data type. Datetime is a class with various properties: one of them is Day, which is an integer.

So if we were to have 2 instances of type Datetime, they will in turn have a member called day, which are both integers. In this case, since you have to subtract 2 integers, the result must be saved inside an integer type variable.

If you want to test, just add x days to today date. For example:

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(200);
    
int daysDiff = (futureDate - current).Days;
    
switch (daysDiff)
{
                    case 200:
                        Console.WriteLine("200");
                        break;
    
                    default:
                        break;
}
```